# Why is an int resetting to zero after each iteration of for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

As title says, I have a very simple for loop where a cumulative variable += the value of a calculation. However, after each iteration, my variable is being reset to zero. Why?

Here's my loop:

```
int score_board(board* b)
{
    int i;
    int total_score = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("CURRENT TOTAL = %d\n",total_score);
        total_score += score_line(grab_line(b, i, 0));
        total_score += score_line(grab_line(b, i, 1));
        printf("scored row and columnn %d\tcum total=%d\n", i, total_score);
    }

    return total_score;
}
```

And here's the output I'm getting, proving that while total_score does get set to the value I want during one iteration, it loses its value upon resetting the for loop:

```
CURRENT TOTAL = 0
line score = 11000
line score = 40000
scored row and columnn 0        cum total=51000
CURRENT TOTAL = 0
line score = 60000
line score = 50000
scored row and columnn 1        cum total=110000
CURRENT TOTAL = 0
line score = 20000
line score = 40000
scored row and columnn 2        cum total=60000
CURRENT TOTAL = 0
line score = 50000
line score = 50000
scored row and columnn 3        cum total=100000
```

EDIT:
Found it! Inside of score_line, the int that I eventually return wasn't initialized to zero. Rookie mistake.

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you please psot the code of the function score_line and for the function grab_line?

Comment: It's either because a bug in your score_line() or grab_line() function, or this is not the actual code that's run.

Comment: check the out put of score_line(grab_line(b,i,0));

Comment: Are you sure `int total_score = 0;` isn't been placed inside the loop?

Comment: Compile with symbols and step through the code using a debugger, doing so inspect the value of `total_score`.

Comment: How does making it `static` solve anything? It just makes the function harder to get right and non-reentrant.

Comment: @larsmans sorry, it won't.

Comment: @larsmans making it static (temporally) *could* help diagnose the possible problem of `score_line()` accessing out-of-bounds elements.

Comment: Replace temporarily `total_score += score_line(grab_line(b, i, 0));` by `total_score += 1 ;` and look what happens. If it works, then you may have an out of bounds or similar problem in `score_line` or in `grab_line`.

Comment: There most definitely is something else than what has been shown to us by the question. Although obvious, here, I have extended the code into a fully working one, which displays the expected result, instead of a resetting `total_score`: http://ideone.com/C1HWDZ

Comment: Please check whether your binary executable is up to date with the source code. You wouldn't be the first to forget recompiling after making essential source changes, or to have outdated `bin` folders.

Comment: So you guys are right; commenting out score_line and replacing it with "4" gives me a cumulative total of 32, as expected.  Can you help me figure out why score_line could possibly produce an int which doesn't get remembered? I've edited my original post to include the code for scoreline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[to "long" for a comment]

temporarily comment out the calls to `score_line` and `grab_line` and replace them this integers...

```
total_score += 42; // score_line(grab_line(b, i, 0));
total_score += 42; // score_line(grab_line(b, i, 1));
```

and see if you get the same results, if you don't re-enable one of the score_lines and test again, etc... sub-divide the problem down until you find the offending function call.

Comment: Michael - it's a comment to help diagnose the answer given incomplete source code.

Comment: Sure it's a comment. That's why it belongs into the comment section of the question.